# Tensorflow - How to convert feature_column to vector

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am building a `Array[feature_column]` but I need to pass my dataframe to a custom estimator which take `tf.placeholder` as input.

Is there a way to pass my dataframe through something to convert my `feature_column` to the raw `placeholder` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer there: https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/feature_columns

Basically the answer is about this line:

```
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
```